# Spring cloud consul with Turbine configuration

Tags: spring-cloud

I am updating to use turbine with consul and from the documentation I see this section:

---

```
application.yml

spring.application.name: turbine
applications: consulhystrixclient
turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: ${applications}
  appConfig: ${applications}
```

The clusterConfig and appConfig sections must match, so it’s useful to put the comma-separated list of service ID’s into a separate configuration property.

---

So what should I put into the applications?  Is this the actual service names?

It's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are service ids. The [documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-consul.adoc#hystrix-metrics-aggregation-with-turbine-and-consul) says that

```
Turbine uses the DiscoveryClient interface to lookup relevant instances
```

Feel free to open a pull request or issue if you'd like.